# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint on insert

Tags: c#, linq, primary-key, conflict

I have a simple table:

```
IPAddress (PK, string)
Requests (int)
```

It's a flood limiter.  Every minute the tables data is deleted.  Every page request, the `Requests` count increments for given `IPAddress`.

It works great, and our website performance has increased significantly as we do suffer some accidental/intentional effective DDOSes due to the nature of our product and website.

The only problem is, when an IP does send thousands of requests a minute to our website for whatever reason, we get these errors popping up:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_v2SiteIPRequests'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.v2SiteIPRequests'. The duplicate key value is ([IP_ADDRESS]). The statement has been terminated.

The code that makes the insert is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Call everytime a page view is requested
/// </summary>
private static void DoRequest(string ipAddress)
{
    using (var db = new MainContext())
    {
        var rec = db.v2SiteIPRequests.SingleOrDefault(c => c.IPAddress == ipAddress);
        if (rec == null)
        {
            var n = new v2SiteIPRequest {IPAddress = ipAddress, Requests = 1};
            db.v2SiteIPRequests.InsertOnSubmit(n);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            rec.Requests++;
            db.SubmitChanges();

            // Ban?
            if (rec.Requests >= Settings.MAX_REQUESTS_IN_INTERVAL)
            {
                BanIP(ipAddress);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's the best way to handle this exception, and why is it being thrown?  Is a `try catch` best here?

Comment: Is your insert Async?

Comment: @asif, wouldn't it have to be?  It's a web app.  Race conditions are implicit.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

Answer (score 5):

If you get two requests simultanously, the following happens:

```
Request one: is it in the database?
Request two: is it in the database?

Request one: No, not yet
Request two: No, not yet

Request one: INSERT
Request two: INSERT

Request one: WORKS
Request two: FAILS (already inserted a split second before)
```

There is nothing you can do here but catch the exception and handle it gracefully. Maybe by using a simple "try again" logic.

Comment: Same with the increment logic too, albeit, that wouldn't blow up so readily

Comment: @RowlandShaw If it were real SQL, you could handle it by doing "UPDATE TABLE SET REQUESTS = REQUESTS + 1 WHERE...", but with ORMs... I don't like ORMs. They frequently hinder me doing my work :)

Comment: @nvoigt Yeah, that's exactly why my ORM had an update method, so you could just call `.Update(i => i.Requests = i.Requests + 1)`. In most ORMs, you at least have access to the underlying connection so you can write a custom SQL to handle these cases. Or, of course, you can always use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few race conditions there, especially when there are concurrent connections.

You may need to change approach, and always store each request, and then query if there are more in the timeframe than permitted and take whatever action you need

Comment: Thanks, that approach does sound better in retrospect!  Is a `try catch` going to be a good enough solution in this case if I don't want to change the approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution based on suggestions.  It's ugly but works as far as I can tell.

```
/// <summary>
/// Call everytime a page view is requested
/// </summary>
private static void DoRequest(string ipAddress)
{
    using (var db = new MainContext())
    {
        var rec = db.v2SiteIPRequests.SingleOrDefault(c => c.IPAddress == ipAddress);
        if (rec == null)
        {
            // Catch insert race condition for PK violation.  Especially susceptible when being hammered by requests from 1 IP
            try
            {
                var n = new v2SiteIPRequest {IPAddress = ipAddress, Requests = 1};
                db.v2SiteIPRequests.InsertOnSubmit(n);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Can't reuse original context as it caches
                    using (var db2 = new MainContext())
                    {
                        var rec2 = db2.v2SiteIPRequests.Single(c => c.IPAddress == ipAddress);
                        rec2.Requests++;
                        db2.SubmitChanges();
                        if (rec2.Requests >= Settings.MAX_REQUESTS_IN_INTERVAL)
                        {
                            BanIP(ipAddress);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    // Shouldn't reach here
                    Error.Functions.NewError(ee);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rec.Requests++;
            db.SubmitChanges();

            // Ban?
            if (rec.Requests >= Settings.MAX_REQUESTS_IN_INTERVAL)
            {
                BanIP(ipAddress);
            }
        }
    }
}
```